# Getting Mapping error in OLE DB Destination when use SQL Command under Data Access Mode

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am working SSIS integration using Visual Studio 2017. I have tested 'Data Access Mode' Table Or View which did work. Now I need to filter data and I am trying to use 'Data Access Mode' SQL Command and getting Mapping issue in OLE DB Destination Editor.

In Destination Data outsource, I use OLE DB Destination and under 'Component Properties' SQL Command I type following script

```
INSERT INTO User_Filtered
       (UserGUID
       ,IdNum
       ,FirstName
       ,LastName
       ,Email
       ,PostCode)
 VALUES
       (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

In mapping getting error

### error

```
error at user dataflow [ole db destination] no column information was returned by the SQL Command
```

Under the OLD DB Source I typed following script under the SQL Command dataview, which seems fine

```
 SELECT u.*
 FROM [AnotherServer].[dbo].[Users] AS u
 where [email] IS NOT NULL AND [org] IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OLE DB Destination you only need to use a `SELECT` statement with the columns that will be inserted into, not an `INSERT` statement.  After this you can map the columns on the Mappings page.

Comment: Since I am new to SSIS, I was following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BwSsp9_WjU ..... have look at time 3:05.

Comment: he did uppdate script here

Comment: That is for an OLE DB Command, not Destination.  If you only want to load the rows the Command component isn't necessary.

Comment: I slightly confuse, so I need to pick data from another database and insert into another database where both database schema are different.. which one I need here, OLE DB Command or OLE DB Destination??

Comment: You'll want to use an OLE DB Destination for this.